# iSight not working on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, macbook, camera

My cam has not been working since I've installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my Macbook White 2009... Unfortunately I installed it upon a new SSD and don't have the original Mac to extract the iSight firmware from...

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8300 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight (no firmware loaded)
```

Succesfully did `sudo apt install isight-firmware-tools` and even did a `dpkg -i isight-firmware-tools_1.6-4_amd64`, but `lsusb` keeps on giving me

> no firmware loaded...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the isight firmware from the MacOS installation or from elsewhere. See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight